# Chrome 'paused in debugger' issue

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I don't know what I've switched on (by accident) but every time I have the Inspect Element area open and then try to click anything on the webpage not within the Inspect Element area (especially something jQuery related like a slideshow for example) it greys the page, shows a message saying 'Paused in debugger' and then opens a jQuery file within the Sources section of Inspect Element.

Within the 'Call Stack' area, it shows a message saying 'Paused on a "click" Event Listener'.

I don't remember switching this feature on but I'm keen for it to be switched off.

I know this question has been asked before - I thought I'd found the answer when everyone suggested we look to see if the 'Pause' option is switched on (blue).  However, it's not switched on, it's grey not blue or any other colour and when I hover over it, it says "Don't pause on exceptions. Click to Pause on all exceptions".

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You might also check the Source tab, check under the Event Listener Breakpoints panel if you've set any breakpoints under 'Mouse'.

Comment: This panel is in the same section of the console that the "paused" message is in, you just have to scroll way down.

Comment: It wasn't exactly under mouse, but on a couple of other checkboxes under Event Listener Breakpoints - thanks! Firefox proves to be more *stable* when it comes to dev tools.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks for this almost 7 year old comment lol

Answer (score 17):

This can also cause the issue

Break Point icon at top left should be blue like this(For Deactivate BreakPoints)

[image]

Should not grey like this

[image]

Comment: Wow... that's totally not obvious. :)

Answer (score 12):

Found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5174978/733034), if the little octagonal stop/pause sign (at lower left of Chrome "Sources") is colored (blue or purple), you need to click on it until it's black again.

Answer (score 3):

It did drive me nuts for a short while.....scroll all the way to the bottom[image] of breakpoint window and you'll find `XHR Breakpoints` & under it there is the `Any XHR` checkbox...

Answer (score 2):

Goto the sources tab and check all breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Elements** tab and remove all breakpoints from right pane under **DOM Breakpoints**

Comment: I've just checked and there's nothing there, it just says 'no breakpoints'

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio Users, just go Tools>Options>Debugging and make disabled it

Comment: Put me on track :) I could clear the breakpoints in Chrome, but then they would re-appear? Of course that was because VS Code was remote-control-adding breakpoints again :)

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause, it that you've enabled the "pause on exceptions" (the little stop-sign shaped icon with the pause (||) symbol with in in the lower left of the window). Try clicking that back to the off/grey state (not red nor blue states) and reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I resolved it by temporarily disabling the Chrome Bitwarden extension.

You could check to see in the `Sources` tab in the devtools panel to see what is causing this error, it could be an extension.

To open the devtools panel on Chrome, press the `F12` key.

Answer (score 0):

For me what fixed it was to uncheck the "Pause on __ exceptions".

Note the yellow checked box on the right 'debugger' panel:

[image: Note the yellow checked box on the right 'debugger' panel]

Answer (score 0):

Your debugger is paused while you want to run your Flutter project. if any exceptions stop your project, and you still want to run the project, make sure to *untick* the Uncaught exceptions.

[Picture is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLcwO.png)