# Why does jQuery stop debugger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception, google-chrome-devtools

I noticed a strange problem when enabling the "break on exception" feature, in Firefox or Chrome/Chromium. It stops on

```
push.apply( results,
    newContext.querySelectorAll( newSelector )
);
```

even though apparently there is no error on this line. Is this an issue with jQuery, or Firefox?

When I turn off the pause-on-exception, it doesn't show exceptions in console.

The top caller on the stack was `jQuery.fx.tick` at the time of exception.

Comment: what version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: Firefox 22, but Chromium does exactly the same.

Comment: If you look at the source surrounding that fragment, it's wrapped in a try/catch with an empty catch clause meant to swallow any errors silently. That is why you don't get any errors in the console. Why querySelectorAll fails, I can't say, but you can edit the source to add some logging and see what error is thrown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174968/why-is-chrome-pausing-on-some-line-inside-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
Array.prototype.push.apply( results,
    newContext.querySelectorAll( 'div')
);
```

The `push` method you are looking for is a prototype method of `Array` type.

or as a short hand

```
[].push.apply( results,
    newContext.querySelectorAll( 'div')
);
```